# C++/C# path/vector drawing library (2D)

Tags: c#, c++, vector, path, drawing

I'm looking for a toolkit / library which can help me drawing polygons, vectors and paths. Beside actually drawing the 2D elements, the library should also be able to draw handles to the base points of those elements, so I am able to move them by drag & drop. This means the lib also handles the picking routines (or at least allows me to define callbacks).

Please see the image below of a path containing single lines as well as cubic Bezier curves (including some handles and an enclosing rectangle of the full path):

[example image of path including handles and enclosing rectangle](http://s29.postimg.org/l0yp5v485/path_draw.png)

I'm not sure if there's such a library (in C++/C#). Haven't been able to find one yet. Am I stuck with drawing all the elements in this example graph by myself?

Thank you for reading!

Paule

Comment: StackOverflow is not [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Please see what is on topic before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many demands. I used to use Qt, it's convenient. Using signal and slot to implement callback is very easy. Qpainter can draw many shapes, but i'am not sure it can meet your requirement. You can learn more about Qt, it has many demos to learn.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm used to Qt, but I was hoping there's some higher-level approach than having to draw every element manually. Seems I have to.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL satisfies all your requests, and implementing what you want seems not quite difficult.

To get started, you can refer to

http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/setup-basics/

Using GLUT, you can easily created OpenGL windows, create and draw figures. 
Mouse and keyboard events also have callbacks, in which you can add your handler. Even if you don't want to use GLUT, there are numerous tutorials telling you how to get started with OpenGL.

Once you are familiar with basic OpenGL skills, there is also a tutorial on how to create something more complex, like Bezier curves, using OpenGL. Although this tutorial doesn't works exactly as you want, you can still add control points, and drag & drop using glut functions.

http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/bezier_patches__fullscreen_fix/18003/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Qt allows to integrate OpenGL (without the boilerplate code), so I consider using some OpenGL. (Unfortunately I can only mark one answer as "solution".)

Comment: That's all right :) Actually now I'm working on a project using OpenGL for graphics, and Qt, for user interface. Although I'm also new to opengl, programming with it is really exciting!